# Custom View stealing focus from Button

Tags: android, focus, android-custom-view

[image: Layout of the file]

This is my xml file for the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/idtop"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00ff00"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/idalarmtime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="30dip"
        android:paddingTop="30dip"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="100sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/lclock"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff0000" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/idsnooze"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:paddingBottom="30dip"
        android:text="Snooze"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/iddismiss"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:paddingBottom="30dip"
        android:text="Dismiss"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" >
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Code of the Custom View
    package com.exercise.AndroidAlarmService;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
 import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawView extends View {
static AlarmClock a;
static int makemove = 0;
int snooze_co[];
int dismiss_co[];
Vibrator v;

public DrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setFocusable(true); // necessary for getting the touch events

    // setting the start point for the balls
    Point point1 = new Point();
    point1.x = 150;
    point1.y = 20;

    snooze_co = new int[2];
    dismiss_co = new int[2];
    snooze_co[0] = (int) (AlarmDialogActivity.screenWidth * 0.10);
    snooze_co[1] = (int) (AlarmDialogActivity.screenHeight * 0.70 * 0.5);
    dismiss_co[0] = (int) (AlarmDialogActivity.screenWidth * 0.70);
    dismiss_co[1] = (int) (AlarmDialogActivity.screenHeight * 0.70 * 0.5);
    v = (Vibrator) AlarmDialogActivity.who
            .getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    long[] pattern = { 0, 200, 500 };
    v.vibrate(pattern, 0);

    // declare each ball with the ColorBall class
    Drawable dr = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.clock);
    dr.setBounds(100, 50, dr.getIntrinsicWidth(), dr.getIntrinsicHeight());
    a = new AlarmClock(context, R.drawable.clock , point1);

    Log.w("where", "Positions: " + snooze_co[0] + " " + snooze_co[1] + " "
            + dismiss_co[0] + " " + dismiss_co[1]);

}


// the method that draws the balls
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // canvas.drawColor(0xFFCCCCCC); //if you want another background color

    // draw the balls on the canvas
    canvas.drawBitmap(a.getBitmap(), a.getX(), a.getY(), null);

}


// events when touching the screen
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int eventaction = event.getAction();

    int X = (int) event.getX();
    int Y = (int) event.getY();

    switch (eventaction) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // touch down so check if the finger is on
                                    // a ball
        Log.w("where", "makemove" + makemove);
        int centerX = a.getX() + 50;
        int centerY = a.getY() + 50;

        // calculate the radius from the touch to the center of the ball
        double radCircle = Math
                .sqrt((double) (((centerX - X) * (centerX - X)) + (centerY - Y)
                        * (centerY - Y)));
        if (radCircle < 45) {
            makemove = 1;
            break;
        }

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // touch drag with the ball
        // move the balls the same as the finger
        Log.w("where",
                "makemove" + makemove + " " + a.getX() + " " + a.getY());
        if (makemove == 1) {
            a.setX(X - 50);
            a.setY(Y - 50);
            int cenX = a.getX();
            int cenY = a.getY();

            double rad1 = Math
                    .sqrt((double) (((cenX - dismiss_co[0]) * (cenX - dismiss_co[0])) + (cenY - dismiss_co[1])
                            * (cenY - dismiss_co[1])));
            double rad2 = Math
                    .sqrt((double) (((cenX - snooze_co[0]) * (cenX - snooze_co[0])) + (cenY - snooze_co[1])
                            * (cenY - snooze_co[1])));

            // if the radius is smaller then 23 (radius of a ball is 22),
            // then
            // it must be on the ball
            if (rad1 < 40) {
                Log.w("where", "Dismiss");
                v.cancel();

            }
            if (rad2 < 40) {
                Log.w("where", "Snooze");
            }

        }

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        makemove = 0;
        Log.w("where", "makemove" + makemove);
        break;
    }
    // redraw the canvas
    invalidate();
    return true;

}
}
```

**What I am trying to do -** I have a linear layout with id 'layc'. I am creating a new View that I am adding to this LinearLayout with addView. This custon view is draggable. When I drag it to dismiss, a function will be called.

**The issue -** The snooze and dismiss buttons are not receiving onTouch / onClick Events when the new View is added

Comment: Do you have the code for the custom view your adding? In particular does it override onInterceptTouchEvent() and return true? If it does it's stealing the touch, so you'd need to modify the logic to suit your needs.

Comment: @Ryan I've added the code.. plz check the editted question.